# how to disable fast forward in youtube player API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, youtube-api

```js
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'app';
 player: YT.Player;
 private id: string = 'X_5_BLt76c0';
 public tt;
 constructor() {

 }
 savePlayer(player) {
   this.player = player;
   console.log('player instance', player.control)
 }
 
 onStateChange(event) {
   console.log("State CHanges");
 }
 

 ngOnChange() {
   console.log(this.player.getCurrentTime())
 }
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<youtube-player
     [videoId]="id"
     (ready)="savePlayer($event)"
     (change)="onStateChange($event)" [playerVars]="{'controls': 2,'modestbranding':1,'disablekb':1,'autohide':2}" allowfullscreen ></youtube-player>
```

hello i am using angular 2. i am using ng2-youtube-player for playing youtube videos. i want to prevent some controle like fast forward. video should not move forward in any case by user input.how can i disable fast forward option.

Comment: what's `youtube-player`? I'd guess this is some third party plugin?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways this can be done

1. Using controls in iframe
2. Using javascript

1) For javascript you can refer the following link on codepen.
[Youtube iFrame API & Angular.js](https://codepen.io/adamtowle/pen/BoZjyZ)

```
 // This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)


// after the API code downloads.
  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    $scope.player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '180',
      width: '180',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      },
      playerVars: { 
        'controls': 0,
        'showinfo': 0
      }
    });
  }
```

2) For Iframe you can use the following links
[YouTube Iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player)